# Cypress problem with type into date input

Tags: date, input, cypress, e2e

I'm trying to create E2E test using cypress on my Vue site. I'm using cypress 11.0.

[image: 1]

When I try using .type() on my data input field I got an error like on screen.

[image: 2]

```
   cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .form-control').type("1999-02-01", { force: true })
```

It worked onece, but now it doesn't. I've tried .click(), .focus() before .type().
I've cleared chrome cashe and re-run cypress many times.

It's my first question on stack :P

I've tried every easy solution. I'm expecting input a data to date field using cypress type or by click on date input.

Comment: The date box is asking for a certain date format which you are not following. Could that be related to your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always depends on the Date field UI.

If it is with an input tag you can try

```
cy.get(':nth:child(3) > .form-control').clear().type('1999-02-01')
```

If not, it might be the date picker type. You can try to click it on the field and add the additional script.

```
cy.get(':nth:child(3) > .form-control').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Callbacks for Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then#Change-subject)

Something that just worked for me is waiting for the callback to get invoked when you use `get`

Example:

```
cy.get(selectors.initialDate).then(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).focus();
    cy.wait(250);
    cy.wrap($el).type(`{esc}`);
    cy.wait(250);
    cy.wrap($el).type(`01/15/2012`);
});
```

You might not have to use the `wait` periods like we are, we are just now having to throttle down the speed at which cypress executes, and are having to take a rudimentary first approach to making sure our concept is going to work before we spend hours changing our whole test suite.

But, long story short, try just getting the selector then waiting until cypress actually has it using the `.then` callback. It might just be stepping on itself.

Also, I recommend trying to select the element using something unique, like `attr.data-cy="some_unique_name"`

Then you can find that element much easier.

Like my selector in this example is something like:

```
const selectors = {
   initialDate: `mat-form-field[data-cy="initialDate"] input`;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cypress.Commands.add("materialUIDatePicker", (date_From_Test_Data) => {
const [month, day, year] = date_From_Test_Data.split("/");

```
cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .MuiButton-label > .MuiTypography-root").then(($div) => {
    const currentYear = $div.text();
    if (currentYear !== year) {
        cy.get(":nth-child(1) > .MuiButton-label > .MuiTypography-root").click();
        cy.contains(year).click();
    }
});

cy.get(".MuiPickersSlideTransition-transitionContainer > .MuiTypography-root").then(() => {
    const months = [
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];
    const monthIndex = months.indexOf(month) + 1;
    const selectMonth = monthIndex - parseInt(date_list_from_Test_Data[0]);
    if (selectMonth !== 0) {
        const buttonIndex = selectMonth > 0 ? 1 : 2;
        const clicks = Math.abs(selectMonth);
        for (let i = 0; i < clicks; i++) {
            cy.xpath(`/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button[${buttonIndex}]`).click({ force: true });
        }
    }
});

cy.wait(3000);

cy.get(".MuiPickersCalendar-transitionContainer")
    .find(".MuiButtonBase-root > .MuiIconButton-label")
    .each(($ele) => {
        const v = $ele.get(0).innerText;
        if ($ele.is(":visible") && v === day) {
            cy.wrap($ele).click();
        }
    });

cy.get(".MuiDialogActions-root > :nth-child(2) > .MuiButton-label").click();
```

});
USE THIS IN CYPRESS CMD CHANGE ELEMENTS AS PWER REQUIREMENTS I USED THIS IN MERN PROJECT